# How can I make text vertical (rotated 90 deg) in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I make `<Text />` vertical (rotated 90 deg) in react native?  I want to have some text on the right side of the page along the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

You can use a transformation.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms.html#proptypes

```
myStyle: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}]
}
```

Comment: @JacobLauritzen it works in React Native! I've tested right now and it works with version 0.52.0.

Comment: @shimatai awesome! I was replying to a previous (now deleted) comment, though, not the solution. The solution works great.

Comment: For my case, the text is wrapped in a Touchable. And after rotation, the touchable area seems remain unchanged. Any idea?

Comment: @chengsam Offhand I would guess that you might need to also rotate the Touchable (or maybe rotating the Touchable will also rotate the text if it's a child).

Comment: Does anyone have an idea if negative values are recommended, such as -15 instead of 345?

Answer (score 22):

In style, use transform to rotate and element

```
style={{transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }]}}
```

E.g.:

```
<View style={{transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }]}} />
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using Material-UI Typography with makeStyles(), this should work :

```
myClassName: {
    transform: "rotate(90deg)"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

create the view:

```
<View style={styles.arrow_1_6} ></View>
```

add in style transform: `[{ rotate: '14deg' }]`, if you make view position absolute it will not affect another view!

The rotation starts from 0 to 360 deg.

```
arrow_1_6: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '14deg' }],
    width: 260,
    marginTop: 145,
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: 75,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    height: 4,
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    borderBottomColor: '#075fff',
    borderBottomWidth: 4,      
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In style, use transform to rotate and element

```
style={{transform: "rotate(90deg)"}}
```

it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I always use this one, try it out

```
<p style={{transform: 'rotate(91deg)'}}>.......</p>
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.